# Что не так в коде (работа с массивами)?

Tags: php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>урок</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

    $langs [
        'ru'=>['пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб', 'вс'],
        'en'=>['mo', 'tu', 'we', 'th', 'fr', 'sa', 'su']
    ];

    echo $langs['ru'][0].', '.$langs['en'][2]

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$langs [` знак присваивания где?

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо добавить оператор присваивания. Должно получиться так:

```
$langs = [
    'ru'=>['пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб', 'вс'],
    'en'=>['mo', 'tu', 'we', 'th', 'fr', 'sa', 'su']
];
```

Comment: Спасибо, я всё понял и в прошлый раз :)